# How Does Voltmeter Actually Work?

Tags: electric-circuits, electricity, electric-current

I've tried to find a specific answer to my question, but couldn't.

My question is why Voltmeter Shows Zero Volts, when we connect the leads not across a resistor (or any other component) but side by side the wire itself. This way Voltmeter is still connected in parallel. If current goes through lead A and leaves through Lead B and back to the wire (event if very small amount of current) then Voltmeter still should show some value, doesn't it?

I understand that Voltage is the difference of potentials, but how does Voltmeter read these potentials? Does it mean that both the leads of the Voltmeter read potentials from two different places? I have searched for this but most gave the answer that no it's just one lead reads, and the current flows out through the other.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In a realistic scenario, the voltmeter will *not* read a voltage of zero as you suspect. However, the value will be extremely small (unless the wires have a significant resistance), and it may show value of zero if it does not have a high precision.

In the idealistic scenario however, the voltmeter will *necessarily* read zero because the one of the main consequences of idealization in DC circuits is that the wires have no significant resistance, and as a consequence, from an equation derived from Ohm's law we find $$\Delta V = IR \approx I(0\Omega) = 0$$
which is why the voltmeter will show a value of zero. A physical explanation for this result is that as the resistance of the wires is zero, all of the current passes through these wires, and none through the voltmeter. It follows that in the realisitc scenario, the resistance of the wires is not assumed to be negligible.

> How does voltmeter read these potentials

It depends on the type of voltmeter used. A moving coil DC voltmeter works like [this](https://www.codrey.com/electrical/moving-coil-meter/).

Since voltmeters display the voltage, they may otherwise make use of Ohm's law to determine the voltage between two points. This method does not  need the absolute potentials at either points, but would rather need the resistance and current passing through the voltmeter, which can be measured easily. Such a device is also called the [multimeter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multimeter)

Hope this helps.